# Explicit Fractional Basis Expansion

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, decimal-expansion

We can write any $x\in\mathbb R$ as its $b>1\in \mathbb N$ basis expansion:

$$x=sgn(x)\sum_{d=-\infty}^\infty b^d \lfloor |x|b^{-d} - b\lfloor |x|b^{-d-1} \rfloor \rfloor$$

Can one come with the same kind of explicit expansion that would be valid for any rational $b=p/q$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes; this is known as [Non-integer representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-integer_representation) or $\beta$-expansion.